# Determining whether a number is prime or not in Java using for loops

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm fairly new to java and I've acquired some programming experience over the past year with python and C++; however, I find java to be a lot more confusing. What I am trying to do here is determine whether or not a number (user input) is prime or not through the use of for loops. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x)
{
    boolean prime = true;
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        prime = false;
    if (x % 2 != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 3; i*i <= x; i+=2)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
                prime = false;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```

I've been stuck on this for quite some time and if anyone could help me figure this out, that'd be great.

Comment: Any error you getting ?

Comment: Your code will return true for 1 but 1 is not a prime number. Also, 2%2=0 so your code will return false for 2 though it is a prime number.

Comment: What should we figure out? How do you call that method, what do you expect and what do you get instead? Why do you expect what you expect?

Comment: The error I'm getting is that for any number I enter into a second program I've made which runs this method, I keep receiving false. I'm quite confused on where to go from here. I just want to be able to enter "2", and have the output be true, or enter "6", and have the output be false.

Comment: Not those numbers in specific, but the whole intention of the program is just that as an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Well, the first thing you do is `if (x % 2 == 0)
        prime = false;`. And 2 % 2 is 0. So, there's your bug for 2. 6 is not prime, so the result you get is correct. For any other number where th returned value is incorrect, execute your code step by step, by hand, r using a debugger. That technique applies to any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution returns true for 1 and false for 2

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x)
{
    if(x<2)
    return false; 
    if(x==2)
    return true;
    // boolean prime = true; you dont need the variavle
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        return false;
// using return is faster as you dont need to do more conditions
// also, you dont need the if. You could use else, if you dont want to return
// immediately   
        for (int i = 3; i*i <= x; i+=2)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
                return false;
        }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.